# Is there any alternate for Powermock and Jmockit to mock static and private methods?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock, junit5

I am trying to mock private, static methods in JDK11 Junit5 environment. Junit5+Powermock+JDK11 isn't working for me. Jmockit is working in STS but not working in VSCode.

Could anyone please suggest different ways to mock static and private methods with respect to Junit5 and JDK11?

Edit: In my case, I have to mock static and private methods just because I'm asked to do so. I'm not in a position to question the design here

Comment: Ideally you should have a build tool to run the tests, something like maven or gradel and not depend on ide to run the tests.

Comment: The best solution is not to mock private methods at all. You should not even care if those methods exist. That's the meaning of a private method. As to static methods - it's not all that bad, but if you need to mock a static method, I would reconsider application's design, cause most probably there's a lack of dependency injection somewhere.

Comment: @pavel You are absolutely correct. It's a poor design. But for some reason I need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since JUnit 5, the platform, allows to have any number of test engines in the same project, you might stick with JUnit 4 for those tests that need Powermock and use Jupiter for the rest.

And you probably want to vote up the issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/201

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I have done it using Jmockit.